# Rails 3.1 obfuscate javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

With Rails 3.1, the [sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) gem was introduced. I have written a very large game engine in javascript/coffeescript which I plan to release as open source software in the future, but at the moment, I would like to obfuscate the code to build a small barrier for people trying to cheat in the game. My question is:

**What do I have to do to create an obfuscated version of the application.js** file which was created by combining all my js files? Is there a best practice, a gem or it is even possible at all?

Thanks for your answer.

Tom

Comment: You should also take a loot at http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use Closure Compiler with advanced optimization, although I would recommend against it:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript

Comment: this a a good approach, though I don't like the advanced optimization, too. Especially with a lot of javascript code, it maybe break something.
Anyway, I think this is the best solution for this problem at the moment

Answer (score 1):

You could try dojo's [ShrinkSafe](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/index.html#minification) - it will minify/obfuscate yoour sources and you can configure it to generate one single file out of several input source files.

Comment: Hm, that could be a way to achieve my goal, but there must be an easier way, something more ruby like. Sprockets create this file on the fly, so there should be a way to add a hook or something to send this file through an obfuscator in some way.